# Use the extra_hosts feature to map requests to other containers?

Tags: docker, dns

`willnorris/imageproxy` is a caching image proxy server that we use in one of our deployments. It will get a request like http://imageproxy:8080/200/https://example.com/myimage.jpg and serve the image from https://example.com/myimage.jpg resized to 200 pixels. That works fine. But how do I route requests that is supposed to end up at other containers? If I had not been running Docker, I would usually just use the `/etc/hosts` feature to map `example.com` to `127.0.0.1, but the imageproxy container has no idea of that file.

Say, I have a PHP server running inside a Docker image at port 8000. What would I do, either on the CLI or in Docker Compose, to make sure that when the `imageproxy` tries to fetch stuff from `example.com` it will get it from the PHP server?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was onto something with the `extra_hosts` thing, but what I was missing was that Docker integrates with the DNS resolving. So when you create a named docker instance, `db`, then you can reach that on the network using the hostname `db`. Maybe the best elaboration is actual code, so below is 99% a docker-compose file that I use for development. The `web` node is reachable from the other containers as `web`, but I also add a DNS alias `web.localhost`. The reason I do this, is that on the *host* (my development machine), I have also aliased `web.localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. This is because I do routing in that webapp based on the `Hostname` header in HTTP requests and the webapp is configured to think its hostname is just this. I don't need the Docker DNS alias for this to work when connecting from my browser, but I do need this when connecting to it *from another container*, as that also need to connect to `web.localhost`.

```
$ cat docker-compose.dev.yml 
version: '2'

services:

  web:
    image: myapp-web:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/myapp  
    ports:
      - "${PF_WEB_PORT:-8000}:8000" # needed to expose on port 8000
    networks:
      development:
        aliases: #dns aliases
          - web.localhost  # makes it possible for imageproxy to resolve http://web.localhost:8000/...

  imageproxy: 
    image: willnorris/imageproxy
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 # needs to be accessible browser. otherwise we would need an nginx reverse proxy
    networks:
      development:
        aliases: #dns aliases
          - cdn.localhost  # makes it possible for web to resolve http://cdn.localhost:8080/...
    
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    ports:
      - "${PF_DB_PORT:-15432}:5432" # required so that we can connect to it externally
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - development

  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/minio:/data
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "19001:9000"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio123
    command: server /data
    networks:
      - development

  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${PF_REDIS_PORT:-16379}:6379"
    networks:
      - development

networks:
  development:
```